# How to substitute ReturnUrl for certain action in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to have different `ReturnUrl` for certain action in my ASP.NET MVC controller. Controller have Authorize attribute and `OnEndRequest` handler do the work for adding `ReturnUrl` to not authorized requests like so:

```
 protected override void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    var location = resp.RedirectLocation;
    ...
 }
```

Then `location` will be used as value for `ReturnUrl` parameter.

The question: Is it possible, in some elegant way like some attribute on action, substitute value in `resp.RedirectLocation` or do it in different way?

Thanks.

Comment: Hej man, I saw your question the other day but I thought you are gonna have a lot of answers, but it doesn't seems like so. 
I don't know if you have resolved this issue, i have created fiddle here with my authorize attr: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5DLGCu please do see if it suits you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can send your return url to your custom Authorize attribute

```
   public class AuthAttribute:ActionFilterAttribute
    {
     private string _returnUrl { get; set; }
     public AuthAttribute(string url)
        {
            _returnUrl = url;
        }
     }
```

Comment: It depends on which way is used by developer to authorize.
For Forms Authentication
if(!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(_returnUrl);}

Comment: within the attribute?